# Tic Tac Toe in Swift

Tags: swift, tic-tac-toe

Any feedback encouraged.  My `checkForWinner` function feels cumbersome to me.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonFour: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonFive: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonSix: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonSeven: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonEight: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonNine: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var gameResult: UILabel!

    var gameState = ["","","",
                     "","","",
                     "","",""
                     ]

    let winningCombos = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], //horizontal
                         [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], //vertical
                         [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]] //diagonals

    var gameOver = false
    var turnCount = 0
    var currentPlayer: String!

    func pickFirstPlayer() -> String {
        if arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 {
            currentPlayer = "o"
        } else {
            currentPlayer = "x"
        }
        return currentPlayer
    }

    func toggleNextPlayer() {
        if currentPlayer == "o" {
            currentPlayer = "x"
        } else {
            currentPlayer = "o"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func makeMove(sender: AnyObject) {
        let space = sender.tag
        if (gameState[space] == "" && gameOver == false) {
            let turnImage = UIImage(named: "\(self.currentPlayer).png")
            sender.setImage(turnImage!, forState: .Normal)
            gameState[space] = self.currentPlayer
            self.toggleNextPlayer()
            self.turnCount++
            self.checkForWinner()
        }
    }

    func checkForWinner() {
        var winner = ""
        for combo in winningCombos {
            var row: [String] = []
            for space in combo {
                row.append(gameState[space])
            }
            if (row[0] == row[1] && row[1] == row[2] && row[0] != "") {
                gameOver = true
                winner = row[0].uppercaseString
                gameResult.text = "\(winner) is the winner!"

            }
        }
        if (turnCount == 9 && winner == "") {
            gameResult.text = "It's a tie!"
            gameOver = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickFirstPlayer()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: To be clear your code only checks for row matches?

Comment: It checks for three in a row, like regular tic tac toe (all the combos listed in winningCombos)

Comment: OK gotcha, hope you get some good answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using strings (in your case: `"o"` and `"x"`) to identify the two
players is inflexible and error-prone:

- If you mistype `"o"` as `"O"` or `"0"` then the program will not work
  properly or crash, and the compiler cannot warn you about that.
- If you decide to use different player names or different names for the image resources then you have to change it at many places.
- The actual display of a player's name as uppercase letter is "hidden"
  at

  ```
  winner = row[0].uppercaseString
  ```

  in `checkForWinner()`.

Defining string constants

```
let playerO = "o"
let playerX = "x"
```

would be one possible solution, but the better way is to use an
*enumeration* which can take exactly two values:

```
enum Player : String {
    case X = "x"
    case O = "o"
}
```

Methods to get the "other" player, the display image, and to select
a random player can be added directly to the `enum` definition:

```
enum Player : String {
    case X = "x"
    case O = "o"

    func other() -> Player {
        switch (self) {
        case .O: return .X
        case .X: return .O
        }
    }

    func image() -> UIImage {
        return UIImage(named: self.rawValue + ".png")!
    }

    static func random() -> Player {
        return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? .O : .X
    }
}
```

This makes the `pickFirstPlayer` and `toggleNextPlayer()` methods
in the view controller obsolete, and `viewDidLoad()` becomes

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentPlayer = Player.random()
}
```

where `currentPlayer` is defined as

```
var currentPlayer: Player!
```

---

To print a player's name, implement the `CustomStringConvertible`
protocol:

```
extension Player : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { 
        return self.rawValue.uppercaseString
    }
}
```

If `winner` is value of type `Player` then

```
gameResult.text = "\(winner) is the winner!"
```

prints the winner's name using the `description` method, and you 
can adopt that to your needs without affecting the rest of the code or the image resource names.

---

Your `gameState` variable describes the contents of the game board,
so I would call it `board` instead. Each field can be empty, or be
occupied by one of the players. This can be modeled by

```
var board : [Player?] = [nil, nil, nil,
    nil, nil, nil,
    nil, nil, nil,
]
```

i.e. an array of *optional* players.

---

I would separate the determination of a possible winner from the
*display* of the outcome, e.g. by defining the method as

```
func checkForWinner() -> Player? { ... }
```

which either returns the winner or `nil`. In that method,

> ```
>        var row: [String] = []
>         for space in combo {
>             row.append(gameState[space])
>         }
> ```

can be simplified using `map()`. Using the new Player type and return type it  would look this:

```
func checkForWinner() -> Player? {
    for combo in winningCombos {
        let row = combo.map { board[$0] }
        if (row[0] != nil && row[0] == row[1] && row[1] == row[2]) {
            return row[0]
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

It would suffice to check only the rows which are changed by the
last move. On the other hand, with 8 winning combinations, that
does not make a big performance difference.

---

Assuming that the `makeMove()` action is connected to *buttons*
only, you should declare it as

```
@IBAction func makeMove(sender: UIButton) { ... }
```

this allows better error checking than `sender : AnyObject`.
(When you create the action in interface builder, there is an option
for that.)

Using all the above stuff, the `makeMove()` method becomes

```
@IBAction func makeMove(sender: UIButton) {
    let space = sender.tag
    if (board[space] == nil && !gameOver) {

        sender.setImage(currentPlayer.image(), forState: .Normal)
        board[space] = currentPlayer
        turnCount++

        if let winner = checkForWinner() {
            gameOver = true
            gameResult.text = "\(winner) is the winner!"
        } else if (turnCount == 9) {
            gameOver = true
            gameResult.text = "It's a tie!"
        } else {
            currentPlayer = currentPlayer.other()
        }
    }
}
```

---

You use the `UIView`'s `tag` property to identify from which button
the action method is called. This is OK, but note that `0` (zero)
is the default tag for all views. It is therefore better to tag the
buttons with `1 ... 9` instead of `0 ... 8`, and adjust that in

```
    let space = sender.tag - 1
```

---

A final note about using `self`: You can access properties and
methods of the current class without using `self` (unless there
is an ambiguity, e.g. due to a local variable or function parameter with the name name, or if `self` is captured implicitly in a block.)

Whether you use `self` or not to access properties is
a matter of taste and programming style,
but in any case it should be *consistent* in your code, which it
currently isn't:

```
self.turnCount++
// ...
gameOver = true
```

(*Remark:* There was a [language proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0009-require-self-for-accessing-instance-members.md) to require self for accessing instance members, which
was [rejected](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160104/005478.html) recently.
Also `++` and `--` [will be deprecated soon and removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md).)

Comment: It's worth noting that `++` may be gone too, right?

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!  I'm actually a little confused about the use of `self`:  all I know is that XCode yelled at me whenever I left it out.  It seems very oddly used, compared to my experience with it in other languages.

Comment: @nhgrif: You are completely right, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @thumbtackthief: There are cases where you have to use self. The first that come into my mind is 1) when the instance member is shadowed by a local variable, 2) when self is captured in a block. – In the code of your question it is – as far as I see – not necessary.

Comment: What's most important is that you are consistent with your inclusion or omission of `self`.  I personally prefer seeing it, but I understand the case for omitting it, and for the sake of consistency with the other devs on projects I work on, I omit it myself.

Comment: Now that I've had time to go through all this and read it more closely, I can't thank you enough--wish I could upvote it more!  Would you be able to explain this line `let row = combo.map { board[$0] }`?  I'm familiar with `map` in Python and it seems it's the same here; I think it's the `$0` I'm unfamiliar with and can't find docs for.  (If this is better as a new SO question, I'm happy to write one up)

Comment: `combo.map { board[$0] }` is shorthand for `combo.map { space in board[space] }` which is again a short form for `combo.map { (space: Int) -> Player? in board[space] }`. – You'll find it under "Shorthand Argument Names" in the Swift book.

Answer (score 1):

What jumps out at me is the nested for loop in checkForWinner.  If I were to try this I'd think more in terms of a different condition for how a winning combo is determined.  We know in this board there are only 3 spots.

It also doesn't seem to make sense to check for winner at the end of each move.  I think I'd just do some kind of recursive check on the neighbors of a given space to see if any are == .